# Inserting html tags in template literals in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, template-literals

I have variable with template literal in React:

```
const weatherForecast = `
  Today in <strong>${this.state.cityName}</strong>
  weather will be with <strong>${today.weather_state_name}</strong>,
  min temperature <strong>${parseInt(today.min_temp)}°C</strong>,
  max temperature <strong>${parseInt(today.max_temp)}°C</strong>,
  and humidity will be <strong>${today.humidity}%</strong>
`;
```

and I want to insert HTML code in it, as you can see that is tag . Is this possible and how can I do this. I googled it, but I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
const weatherForecast = 
`Today in <strong>${this.state.cityName}</strong> weather will be with <strong>${today.weather_state_name}</strong>, min temperature <strong>${parseInt(today.min_temp)}°C</strong>, max temperature <strong>${parseInt(today.max_temp)}°C</strong>, and humidity will be <strong>${today.humidity}%</strong>`;
```

React will treat this as a string and not jsx.
What you can do instead is

```js
const weatherForecast = 
<p>Today in <strong>{this.state.cityName}</strong> weather will be with <strong>{today.weather_state_name}</strong>, min temperature <strong>{parseInt(today.min_temp)}°C</strong>, max temperature <strong>{parseInt(today.max_temp)}°C</strong>, and humidity will be <strong>{today.humidity}%</strong></p>;
```

and then render this in your `render` method like this

```js
render(){
  return <div>{weatherForecast}</div>
}
```

Comment: Can it be, but I use conditional rendering with if else statements in this case, with huge amount of data around this {weatherForecast} variable, therefore I cannot use it in this way. Thanks, anyway for your time.

Comment: @Ivana, but why? JSX allows you using conditionals regardless you want to insert element or plain string

Comment: @Prithwee Das you were right thanks  a lot :) Your answer is the easiest, but you all deserve green checks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) to render HTML from a string with React, but make sure you only use it if you absolutely have to and you control the values.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    cityName: "New York",
    today: {
      weather_state_name: "Foo",
      min_temp: 0,
      max_temp: 10,
      humidity: 50
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { today } = this.state;
    const weatherForecast = `
      Today in <strong>${this.state.cityName}</strong>
      weather will be with <strong>${today.weather_state_name}</strong>,
      min temperature <strong>${parseInt(today.min_temp)}°C</strong>,
      max temperature <strong>${parseInt(today.max_temp)}°C</strong>,
      and humidity will be <strong>${today.humidity}%</strong>
    `;
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: weatherForecast }} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse HTML, because in your case it will show you your  tags instead of making text strong.

You can use for example `import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';`

```
ReactHtmlParser(weatherForecast)
```

Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: weatherForecast }} />
```

You can use this code to display.

Answer (score 1):

Write in JSX:

```
const weatherForecast = <div>
  Today in <strong>{this.state.cityName}</strong>
  weather will be with <strong>{today.weather_state_name}</strong>,
  min temperature <strong>{parseInt(today.min_temp)}°C</strong>,
  max temperature <strong>{parseInt(today.max_temp)}°C</strong>,
  and humidity will be <strong>{today.humidity}%</strong>
</div>;
```

Remember to omit the dollor signs ($)

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar to this issue had to insert elements in attribute i just used some thing like this and it got fixed.

```
<Component title={
   <Fragment>
      <p>Some text <strong>bold text</strong></p>
      <p>Another paragraph <i>text italic</i></p>
   </Fragment>
 } />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const myString = <>{'Util for '}<b>{'yo'}</b></>

return (
    <div>
        {myString}
    </div>
);
```